# Create threads from a dispatch queue block [ swift / c++ ]

Tags: c++, ios, swift, multithreading

I have an iOS app, where the UI is written in swift, but all the heavy work is done with a cross platform c++ library. I communicate with the c++ core from swift using a ObjC wrapper.

I wanted to parallelize the work that is happening in the c++ library, using the thread primitives that c++ provides.

But a piece of data is passed into the c++ library from the swift portion of the app, from within a block in a dispatch queue.

My question is, will those threads that I create within the c++ library be separate from the work queue in swift ? 
From what I understand, it will be. Is that the case ?

Are there any open-source projects which does something similar, or any pitfalls you see with this approach.

The C++ library is a requirement and I can't make it swift only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *will those threads that I create within the c++ library be separate from the work queue in swift ?*

The answer is yes. I'm doing the same things for my app. For C++ library, I believe you will create threads with `pthread_create()` POSIX call. As found in [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html), POSIX threads are totally legal in iOS and the only way to create joinable threads.

Comment: Recommend clarifying for the asker whether or not C++11's  `std::thread` wrapper is in place.

Comment: Good point, Sir. But I haven't used std::thread wrapper with iOS. Have you ?

Comment: Nope. Same boat. I was kind of hoping you knew. clang (and thus XCode) have for years, so I'd expect it to be there. Unfortunately my expectations have been thoroughly abused of late.

Comment: @user4581301 Yep, I wanted to use std::thread with a thread pool. Have you had any threading issues with clang ? I won't expect to, std::thread has been around for a while now.